# Simple regex surrounding a line with <h2> </h2> tags

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm working on learning regex and i found some challenge problems online, but got stumped early on... I'm not very good at this :(. Anyway here is the question that stumped me -

```
Each line beginning and ending with two asterisks gets surrounded with <h2> and </h2>, instead of the asterisks and surrounding white space
```

I know there is something with line starting with and ending with being ^ and & so I thought maybe I should use those to find the "**" then use gsub to substitute in , but then I remembered that would put  in both spots and that's not exactly what I wanted so I got stumped.

Help me please!

Comment: There's a reason [one does not parse or build HTML with a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: @hexafraction: Yeah, expect for the fact that this does not seem to _be_ HTML code in the first place, and rather _text_ including some kind of markdown-like syntax that should be _made into_ HTML code …

Comment: @hexafraction: where have you seen in your link a reason to not build html with regex?

Comment: _“so I thought maybe I should use those to find the "**" then use gsub to substitute in `<h2>`, but then I remembered that would put `<h2>` in both spots”_ – exactly, so the job is not to simply replace the `**`, but to _capture_ what is _inside_ them, and use that _surrounded_ by an opening and a closing `h2` tag to replace the whole match …

Comment: [These things are trickier than you might think](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4231382/471272).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
def doit(str)
  sub = str[/^\s*\*{2}\s*(.*?)\s*\*{2}\s*/,1]
  sub ? '<h2>' + sub + '</h2>' : str
end

str = ' ** Now is the time for all ** '
doit(str) #=> "<h2>Now is the time for all</h2>"

str = ' ** Now is the time for all * '
doit(str) #=> " ** Now is the time for all * "
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question, this is what you need:

```
result = subject.gsub(/\A(\*\*)(.*?)(\*\*)\Z/, '<h2>\2</h2>')
```

***Regex Explanation:***

```
^(\*\*)(.*?)(\*\*)$

Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\*\*)»
   Match the character “*” literally «\*»
   Match the character “*” literally «\*»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(\*\*)»
   Match the character “*” literally «\*»
   Match the character “*” literally «\*»
Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```

Comment: Note the reference in the question to 'whitespace'.

Answer (score 0):

```
string =<<-END_OF_STRING
Foo Bar
**Foo BAR**
Bazz
**Bazz**
**Not** Complete
END_OF_STRING

puts string.gsub(/^\*\*(.+)\*\*$/) { |m| "<h2>#{$1}</h2>" }

# Foo Bar
# <h2>Foo BAR</h2>
# Bazz
# <h2>Bazz</h2>
# **Not** Complete
```

Comment: Consider changing `(.+)` to `(.*)` in case `string => "****"`.  Do you know what time it is?